# Charts.js - Get Y-coordinate of any X-coordinate in Line Chart (with Line-tension)

Tags: chart.js

I have a line chart (with a line-tension of 0.25) with 7 coordinates, at the x-values: -3, -2. -1. 0, 1, 2 and 3. Is it possible to get the y-value of say -0.25, without defining it myself and without using mouse events?

Comment: Please show the code you already have and try to better explain what you're looking for.

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/basic.html.     Thanks for the response. I want to be able to know the Y value of any X on a chart like this, so not just for "February" or "March". Imagine January = 0, February = 1, March = 2, etc. Then I would like to know what the Y value is of 1.5, or 1.75, or 2.15, etc.